# Input data is not a valid image - Microsoft Cognitive Services Vision API

Tags: xamarin, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

when using the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision nuget, and calling RecognizeTextAsync(stream), I get "input data is not a valid image" error back.

The sample repo using xamarin android can be found [here](https://github.com/InquisitorJax/Microsoft-Cognitive-Services-OCR)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the stream before sending it with:

```
request.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```